# NSOutlineView cell-based background glitch while editing in 10.12

Tags: cocoa, nsoutlineview

I have an cell-based NSOutlineView under 10.12 with Source-View highlighting. When I first click on the cell and it goes into edit mode, everything is ok:

[image: Valid Edit]

However, as soon as I start editing, the background turns blue like the highlight.

[image]

I have tried (without success):

```
@interface NonBackgroundDrawingTextView : NSTextView
@end

@implementation NonBackgroundDrawingTextView
-(BOOL)drawsBackground
{
    return NO;
}
@end


-(NSTextView *)fieldEditorForView:(NSView *)controlView
{
    NSTextView* textView = [[NonBackgroundDrawingTextView alloc] initWithFrame:NSZeroRect];
    [textView setFieldEditor:YES];
    [textView setFocusRingType:NSFocusRingTypeDefault];
    return textView;
}
```

Any ideas? It works fine in 10.10 and 10.11.

Comment: Unfortunately, cell-based everything is deprecated. Since that, all those bugs won't be fixed. Use view-based `NSOutlineView` instead.

Answer (score 0):

**Subclass** NSTextFiled, and set datacell to this

**then override**

```
- (void)selectWithFrame:(NSRect)aRect inView:(NSView *)controlView editor:(NSText *)textObj delegate:(id)anObject start:(NSInteger)selStart length:(NSInteger)selLength
{
    NSRect textFrame = [self titleRectForBounds:aRect];

    [super selectWithFrame:textFrame inView:controlView editor:textObj delegate:anObject start:selStart length:selLength];
    [textObj setBackgroundColor:[NSColor whiteColor]];
    [textObj setDrawsBackground:YES];

}
```